# Using method parameter as reference in object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am returning a list of codes called AllCodes from a SQL database. Basic schema like:

```
id | countrycode | refprint | refscan | reffax 
1 . US . 123 . 234 . 345
```

I have a method which should needs to return a a value based on a matching countrycode and whatever column I need from that result.

Here is the method (not working offcourse) but not sure how to achieve this kind of thing with c#

```
  private string GetServiceCode(string cc, string name)
    {
        var code = AllCodes.Where(x => x.CountryCode == cc).FirstOrDefault();
        if (code != null)
        {
            // I want to return whatever {name} is, not code.name
            // so if name = "refprint" I want to return code.refprint
            return code.{name};
        }
    }

  // Example:
  GetServiceCode("US","refprint"); // Would return 123
```

Comment: you could look at [Dynamic Linq](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library) - then it would be `.Select(name)`

Comment: You say list, but are you really using a dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

You could achieve this with reflection:

```
if (code != null)
{
    PropertyInfo pi = code.GetType().GetProperty(name);
    if (pi == null) return string.Empty;
    object v = pi.GetValue(code);
    if (v == null) return string.Emtpy;
    return v.ToString();
}
```

With `GetProperty()` you can get a `PropertyInfo` for the property named `name`. Then you can use `GetValue()` to get the value of the property for a specific instance (`code` in your case).

In C#6 you could shorten the code to

```
return code.GetType().GetProperty(name)?.GetValue(code)?.ToString() ?? string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a lambda:

```
private string GetServiceCode<T>(string cc, Action<T> action)
{
    var code = AllCodes.Where(x => x.CountryCode == cc).FirstOrDefault();
    if (code != null)
    {
        return action(code);
    }
}

// Example:
GetServiceCode("US",(code)=> Console.WriteLine(code.refprint) );
```